# Why does my SQL cluster force me to use the port number to connect?

Tags: sql-server, azure, cluster-computing

I set up my first FCI in Azure. Everything seems to be working except i can only connect to the SQL server when i specify the port number. This doesn't happen with my non clustered instances.

SQLCLuster01\SQL01,1433

I want to drop the 1433 to make it easier for the reps to access SQL. I cant figure out why the cluster needs it. Is it a setting in SQL or is this just how the cluster needs to operate?

Answer (score 0):

[Solved] I found out its because Azure requires a load balancer so Azure itself knows about what ports the cluster is looking for. You need to specify 1433 for the load balancer, you cannot use a cluster in Azure as yet because the ILB doesnt support RPC